# Min sdk version android - Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I want to create an app for Android and I am using **Cordova**.

The Android manifest has `android:minSdkVersion` is `14` (after executing Cordova build android), but I would like a lower value for `android:minSdkVersion` because of the compatibility. Is it safe if I put `10` or another number in the `android:minSdkVersion`? Or which is the lowest version that I can put in the `android:minSdkVersion` in a Cordova project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Peter,
you got a lot of bad advice, which is not new to SO.

One point seldom reiterated – is that when a compiler (or tool set) advance the version number, the software and hardware tend to be [deprecated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation#Software_deprecation), and then later [non grata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persona_non_grata#Non-diplomatic_usage).

When software is ***deprecated***, it is to signal to developers that the software is still available, but is NOT favored for use. This is intend as a *phasing out* stage. It also means that support for this branch has essentially ended. (The rare support that is made is for security reasons, but even [this is ending](https://community.rapid7.com/community/metasploit/blog/2015/01/12/google-no-longer-provides-patches-for-webview-jelly-bean-and-prior).)

When software becomes ***non grata***, this is the signal to developers that the software is *unwelcome*, and should NOT be used. This is intended as the *final* stage, and the removal of the software from general use.

As has been mention in the comments, Android tends to ***deprecate*** software on a milestone basis. (Never mind that the milestone is fabricated and biased.) This deprecation also applies to *Cordova/Phonegap*. In particular, for the [Cordova Tool Set 5.x](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html) (the current tool set), the lowest `android:minSdkVersion` is `14`.

However, as `jcesarmobile` (who I believe is on the official mailing list) has pointed out, if you use [Cordova Tool Set 4.x](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide/platforms/android/index.html) you can compile with your target as `android:minSdkVersion` = `10`.

However, this has issues.

1. You'll have to make sure to use older plugins.
2. You'll have to make sure to save copies of all your support software. (compilers, plugins, etc.)
3. You will be on your own with fixing bugs and security issues.

Fortunately, some of the blogs and documentation is still out there. Cordova has not removed old documentation, so all you need to use the pulldown on your top right (which links to older software documentatio).

You will also want to read this old, but very useful post. It will help you get and save older versions of the software you need. - Best of Luck.

*Cordova/PhoneGap Version Confusion*
http://devgirl.org/2014/11/07/cordovaphonegap-version-confusion/

Answer (score 0):

The minimum sdk you can put is 1, but I seriously do not recommend that. Here is the percentage each sdk version has users: http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html
I recommend making the lowest version to 10. If this stops functionality in your app then choose an sdk that supports your functionality. I personally go with 14.

Comment: as the question is cordova related, it's not possible to se sdk 10 with latest version of cordova, unless you use an old cordova version that still supports sdk 10, see Jesse's answer

Answer (score 0):

It's safe to put in 10, but that means your app can't use any features/functionality in higher SDK versions. Meaning, if a user has a device that only supports sdk v10, and you say is the bare minimum your app needs to run, ensure that your app doesn't use 11+ features.

Comment: as the question is cordova related, it's not possible to se sdk 10 with latest version of cordova, unless you use an old cordova version that still supports sdk 10, see Jesse's answer